# Unable to compare strings.Read EOF error with my own defined error

Tags: go

Can anyone please help me understand why "if err == errEOF" is not evaluating to TRUE and its only works with io.EOF. I know the Strings.Read function is returning io.EOF, but why can't we use the same type and value to evaluate the err?

https://play.golang.org/p/bCp4bZjKW-K

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "io"
)

var errEOF = errors.New("EOF")

func main() {
    r := strings.NewReader("ABCDEFGH")

    buf := make([]byte, 4)
    for {
        n, err := r.Read(buf)

        fmt.Println(n, err, buf[:n])
        //if err == io.EOF { //Loop is breaking only when i use io.EOF
        if err == errEOF { // If i use my own ErrEOF value, It is Not Breaking, Going forever

            break
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Each call to `errors.New` returns a distinct error value even if the text is identical.

Answer (score -1):

```
// Package errors implements functions to manipulate errors.
package errors

// New returns an error that formats as the given text.
func New(text string) error {
    return &errorString{text}
}
```

If you look at the implementation of `New` in `errors` package, it just returns a new instance of `errorString`. So the `var EOF = errors.New("EOF")` from package `io` and your definition are two different errors altogether.

You should not be doing this, but the only way your `errEOF` will work is if you compare `err.String()` to `errEOF.String()`. But you should not be doing this anyways.